# Help identify word - 'Ja imm(?)' with the meaning 'Yes, exactly'

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request, regional

I've heard many times people saying something what I've heard like 'Ja, imm' oder 'Ja, ihm' meaning 'Yes, exactly'. However, I couldn't find such phrase, so I think I could have heard that word not correctly.

What is that word in that phrase? Is it some regionalism (I've heard that in Bavaria), or jargon?

Comment: `Ja, immer`? --> `Yes, always`?

Comment: @alk I'm sure it was used in the meaning, 'exactly', and I haven't heard any sound after 'm'

Comment: Too specialized, ask it in Chat. Nobody will ever have the same question, nor will it be helpful in similar situations. 

Comment: I have also heard version, it can be 'stimmt'

Comment: Not to specialized, see accepted answer. I hear it almost on daily basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you've heard "Ja, eben" which is reduced in speech to "Ja, ehm" which may sound like "Ja, ihm" when e turns to m. The word *eben* is in the meaning of *bestätigt* which means *acknowledged*.